# How to make jailed shell?

Tags: linux, shell, users

How to make jailed shell?

jailed shell means limited shell account for linux users. (as cpanel defination)

I don't use any control panel like cpanel.

Comment: We need way more details of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of documentation available for jail on the net.  What you specifically need will depend on your specific linux distro and what you want to achieve exactly.

A good starting point might be http://rhcelinuxguide.wordpress.com/2006/07/02/linux-jail/ - first Google result for "jail linux".

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative to complex jail is assigning [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) to the concerned user(s).

> lshell is a shell coded in Python, that lets you restrict a user's
>   environment to limited sets of commands, choose to enable/disable any
>   command over SSH (e.g. SCP, SFTP, rsync, etc.), log user's commands,
>   implement timing restriction, and more.